# Simple server-side live search with AngularJS

Tags: python, angularjs

I'm building a search feature for my website, and would like to query a server URL that returns a JSON array of results. I already have everything set up on the server.

What's a simple way to implement an AJAX query against the server, and have the results updated/displayed live?

Comment: Do you want those updates to results to happen regularly without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
<div class="results">
    <div ng-repeat="result in results" ng-bind="result"></div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.$watch('search', function(val){
    $http.get('/api/search', {params: {string: val}}).success(function(data){
         $scope.results = data.results;
    });
});
```

Also you can add debounce to not overwhelm server with requests on every change, i use [loDash](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce).

```
$scope.$watch('search', $scope.debouncedSearch);
$scope.debouncedSearch = _.debounce(function(val){
    $http.get('/api/search', {params: {string: val}}).success(function(data){
         $scope.results = data.results;
    });
}, 200);
```